# Get all subgroup of a group

Tags: algorithm

I have a group of `N` entities.
Is there any way for me to get all subgroups satisfy that the number of entities in each subgroup equals to `M` (`N>M`)?

I will give an example to clarify:

I have `N = 5` integer (e.g: `1,3,4,6,8`).
Is there any way to get all subgroups which contains `L = 3` entities?
Those subgroups are `{1,3,4}`, `{1,3,6}`, `{1,3,8}`, `{1,4,6}`, `{1,4,8}`, `{1,6,8}`, `{3,4,6}`, ...

Seems that it must be a brute-force algorithm.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo-code for a recursive solution:

```
given_array[n]
current_combination[k]

void calculate( max_idx,  cur_idx, cur_count)
{
    if max_idx > cur_idx
        return
    if cur_count==k
        print current_combination
        return

    current_combination.add(given_array[cur_idx])
    calculate( max_idx, cur_idx+1, cur_count+1)
    current_combination.remove(given_array[cur_idx])


    calculate( max_idx, cur_idx+1, cur_count)

}
```

The first call of the function should be as follows:

```
calculate( n, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code for getting nCk

```
getCombinations(set[],i,x,k,buff[]) {

   if(i<k) {

     for(j=x;j<set.size();j++) {

           buff[i] = set[j];
           getCombinations(set,i+1,j+1,k,buff);
     }

   }

   else {   // print combination

        for(y=0;y<k;y++) {

            printf(set[buff[y]]);
        }

   }
}

Call :- getCombinations(set,0,0,k,new int[k]);
```

Comment: What does `buff[j];` means?

Comment: @EliaWeiss Sorry there was a typing error, check my edit